# Querying a cumulative sum of a boolean column per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've been attempting to get a cumulative sum of a boolean column per day. I've tried different ways using either `#sum` and looked up `#distinct` too (by looking at other posts on Stack Overflow) but haven't been able to successfully implement either of those methods in a way I'd like my hash to look.

Currently, this is the query I have:

```
Device.where(boxed: true).group('date(updated_at)').count
```

Which gives me this:

```
{Fri, 17 Apr 2015=>48, Sat, 18 Apr 2015=>44, Sun, 19 Apr 2015=>5, Mon, 20 Apr 2015=>48}
```

But I would like it to look like this:

```
{Fri, 17 Apr 2015=>48, Sat, 18 Apr 2015=>92, Sun, 19 Apr 2015=>97, Mon, 20 Apr 2015=>145}
```

I am using Rails 4 and Postgres. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I ended up doing this to get the cumulative sum, even though this probably is not the best way or elegant at all:

```
data_all_time = Device.where(boxed: true).group('date(updated_at)').count 
data_all_time_keys = data_all_time.keys
data_all_time_values = data_all_time.values
sum = 0
data_all_time_values.map!{|x| sum += x}

all_time_sum_tuple = data_all_time_keys.zip(data_all_time_values)
```

I end up getting something like this:

```
[["April 17, 2015", 48], ["April 18, 2015", 92], ["April 19, 2015", 97], ["April 20, 2015", 145]]
```

Which works for now until I can figure out a better way.

Comment: Which is the difference beetwen 18 Apr 2015=>44 and 18 Apr 2015=>92 for example ? Can you show us somes datas of Device Table

Comment: @tanorix This difference is that on April 18th 44 devices were boxed, but as a total 92 boxes were boxed thus far by adding the total for April 17th and April 18th.

Comment: So you want the counts to be running totals rather than per-date counts?

Comment: @muistooshort that's correct.

Comment: I have an idea, but need to check one thing, is it true that this is for display only, leaving the table data itself unmodified?

Comment: @ValerieAsensio This is for display only. The purpose of this query is to display on a line chart.

Comment: Okay. Please let me check on something before I post an answer.

Comment: I'm glad you have an answer. I'm still thinking it could be achieved entirely in SQL query, and as this is something I may need to do, I'm going to keep looking at it for myself. It is a very good question.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep your sql as is

```
data = Device.where(boxed: true).group('date(updated_at)').count
```

and then do the custom aggregation in ruby

```
result = {}
keys = []
data.each_with_index do |(key, value), index| 
  keys << key
  result[key] = data.values_at(*keys).sum
end
```

the above ruby could be cleaned up a bit, but ...

One other thing to watch out for - subtle time zone issues

```
-- your data is probably stored in UTC and this will group by the UTC dates
'date(updated_at)'
```

depending on where your users are viewing the reports from this may or may not return the counts they expect

- postgres [AT TIME ZONE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) might help you in this case

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up doing something pretty similar to this (which I posted to my question). Thanks for the time zone tip, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Querying a cumulative sum of a boolean column per day:

```
Device.where(boxed: true).group('date(updated_at)').sum('date(updated_at)')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try this query earlier and got some crazy numbers. This is what I get when I tried this query:     {Fri, 17 Apr 2015=>967220016, Sat, 18 Apr 2015=>886618392, Sun, 19 Apr 2015=>100752095, Mon, 20 Apr 2015=>967220160}